# HandsOnTable exportFile

Tags: handsontable

I'm following [this](https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.6.0/demo-export-file.html) example to download my hot into an excel file.

The problem is that it fails doing:

```
var exportPlugin = hot.getPlugin('exportFile');
```

It returns undefined. Needless to say that if i console.log "hot" it's the object I expect.

The version of handsontable is the most recent one to date(1.7.3).

Is there any option in my table that would prevent me from loading the plugin?

I created the hot with the following options:

```
data: sourceData,
colHeaders: colHeaders,
rowHeaders: false,
nestedRows: false,
contextMenu: false,
formulas: true,
comments: true,
columns: columnsProperties,
cell: cellsProperties,
fixedColumnsLeft: categoryColumn+1,
manualColumnFreeze: true,
```

As you can imagine sourceData, colHeaders, columnsProperties and cellsProperties are defined elsewhere.

I can properly visualize the table.

Thank you

SN

Comment: Nevermind, I overlooked the fact that it's available only in the PRO version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a feature on my own project to download the table as CSV file, which you can directly read with excel and of course convert to XLSX format depending on your needs.

See my example in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yhz0kh94/2/)

The following is a generic function to convert your JSON object into the csv file and downloading it (for IE & chrome/Firefox etc..) :

```
function JSONToCSVConvertor(JSONData, colHeaders) {
    var 
    arrData = typeof JSONData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData) : JSONData,
    CSV = '',   
    row = "",
    fileName = "handsontable.csv";

    // Put the header (based on the colHeaders of my table in my example)
    for (var index in colHeaders) {
        row += colHeaders[index] + ';';
    }
    row = row.slice(0, -1);
    CSV += row + '\r\n';

    // Adding each rows of the table
    for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
        var row = "";
        for (var index in arrData[i]) {
            row += arrData[i][index] + ';';
        }
        row = row.slice(0, -1);
        CSV += row + '\r\n';
    }

    if (CSV == '') {
        alert("Invalid data");
        return;
    }        

    // Downloading the new generated csv.
    // For IE >= 9
    if(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        var fileData = [CSV];
        blobObject = new Blob(fileData);
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobObject, fileName);
    } else { 
    // For Chome/Firefox/Opera
        var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);

        var link = document.createElement("a");    
        link.href = uri;

        link.style = "visibility:hidden";
        link.download = fileName;

        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
}
```

You can use it with a button for example :

```
Handsontable.Dom.addEvent(save, 'click', function() {
    JSONToCSVConvertor(hot.getData(), hot.getSettings().colHeaders);
});
```

Note that I use a table with ~10k rows and it works like a charm.

Comment: The pro version works. But thank you for posting your solution!

Comment: This is the correct answer for non-pro version I would venture. That's fab, Fab.

Comment: @SergioNegri what do you say, Sergio? Give fab what he deserves.